# MIPS and matrices

Tags: assembly, matrix, mips, dot-product

I'm dealing with a project for school that involves MIPS and matrices. Basically I have to write a program that, given a N-parameter by input (and this should be the size of my square NxN matrix) and all the elements inside (again, inserted by input from the user) should calculate the dot-product of those two matrices and put the result into a third one.

I first came to this code, which does the dot product but after two static matrices. Not by input.
Two things. How should I change it in order to have both matrices inserted by user (as well for the N size) and, mostly, was my matrix initialization correct?
I didn't do such passage "[(i * num_columns + j)*4] and I'm wondering that what I get is a matter of sheer luck and not rationalization.
Thanks in advance to whomever would like to help me and sorry for any linguistic mistake.

```
.data
v1:     .word 1,2,3,4

    .word 5,6,7,8

    .word 9,10,11,12

v2:     .word 10,20,30,40

    .word 10,10,10,10

    .word 10,10,10,10

v3:     .word 0:12


c: .word 4

space: .asciiz "\n"

.text

main:


li $t0, 0
li $t2, 12
la $t9, c
li $t8, 0


loop:
lw $t3, v1($t0)
lw $t4, v2($t0)

mul $t3, $t3, $t4
addi $t2, $t2, -1

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t3
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, space
syscall

sw $t3, v3($t0)
addi $t0, $t0, 4
addi $t8, $t8, 1
bne $t2, $zero, loop


li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not much one can do to show you how to complete your assignment other than directing you to study the language a bit better. When you run into trouble, post what you have and the problem, and someone will help. Here's a skeleton that may help shed some light on how to start.

```
    .text
main:   
    #call prompt_size       
    #s0 = return val = N

    #a0 = s0: arg = N
    #call new_matrix
    #s1 = return val = address of matrix

    #repeat that two more times

    #call fill_matrix 3 times, sending each matrix address
    #calcuate dot product
    #exit
prompt_size:
    #output prompt
    #read integer
    #return 
new_matrix:
    #t0 = (arg)^2
    #call sbrk(t0)
    #return
fill_matrix:
    #for each byte, prompt for an integer, and insert it
prompt_matrix_element:
    #output_prompt
    #read integer
    #return
exit:
    #exit
```

Comment: Thanks sir, that's indeed a good start. I'm a beginner of this language but suddenly had to fight against these kind of problems. In Java I would solve it without big troubles but on MIPS it is a big issue for a beginner like me to deal with arrays/matrices initialization. Anyway, I'm going to build up my project starting from the shape you showed me. Thanks.